# Concatenate CSV with some shared columns

Tags: text-processing, command-line, awk, sed, csv

I have two large files ~9GB. CSV File 1 has columns `A, B, C, D, E` and CSV File 2 has columns `B, C, F, G`. The desired output is `A, B, C, D, E, F, G`. All I have been able to find is joining on similar columns and concatenating with the same columns, however here some match, and some do not. A sample output would look something along these lines:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G

1   2   3   4   5   6   7

NaN 1   2   NaN 1   2   1
```

So if the value doesn't exist for that column, as in it doesn't exist, I just want it to have a `NaN` value. I hope I have explained the problem well enough. Thanks!

Edit: Normally I would do this in `Python` but these massive files make it considerably more annoying iterating over chunks and then concatenating at the end. There appears to be a more straightforward way using `bash` that I am unaware of. Thanks!

Comment: If column B of file 1 has a value of 10, and column B of file 2 has a value of 20,which one should be kept? Or it is sure that both files will have same values under same columns?

Comment: Also, how are the columns separated? With comma,tab,spaces?

Comment: They are separated by `','` and all values should be kept. Each row of each file corresponds to a different observation if you will. I can adjust the delimiter based on your explanation below, but will keep all the values be effected by your script?

Comment: Give an example jn your main question on how output must be in different values of common columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works based on the following facts:
(a) All fields are strictly tab separated
(b) Common columns in both files (B and C) have the same value

```
$ join --nocheck-order -eNaN -13 -22 -t$'\t' -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.3 2.4 b.txt c.txt
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
NaN 1   2   NaN 1   2   1
```

Files Sample:

```
$ cat b.txt
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   3   4   5
    1   2       1
$ cat c.txt
B   C   F   G
2   3   6   7
1   2   2   1
```

Join Options:
-13 -22 : Join based on file1 column3 (C) = file2 column2 (C)
-t$'\t' : tab delimiter for input and output
-o      : Output format. 1.1 means file1, column1, and so on.
-e      : Fill empty values with NaN
For more info see `man join` and even better `info join`

**Alternative Solution with AWK**
PS: Bear with me in awk, i'm an awk new learner.

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{a[1]="";{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i==6 ||i==7) continue;else \
if ($i!="") a[1]=a[1]FS$i;else a[1]=a[1]FS"NaN";print a[1]}}' <(paste b.txt c.txt)
```

**Update for comma separated input fields**
As advised in your comments , since csv files are separated by comma, this solution will separate input fields by comma and will output the results using tabs to be more readable.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS="\t"}{a[1]="";{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i==6 ||i==7) continue;else \
if ($i!="") a[1]=a[1]OFS$i;else a[1]=a[1]OFS"NaN";print a[1]}}' <(paste b.txt c.txt)
```

If you need output to be printed also with comma , just replace the begine section with `{FS=OFS=","}`

Though is still unclear what you intent to do with common columns / different values.

You can remove the part `if (i==6 ||i==7) continue;else` to see if the results fits your needs. This condition check actually skips field 6 (B column of file2) and field7 (C column of file2) since those two columns of file 2 had been considered as identical to columns of file 1 till now.

For the join solution:
Replace `-t$'\t'` with `-t','` to read comma separated fields

For the common columns you can play with this output format:

```
join --nocheck-order -eNaN -13 -22 -t',' -o 1.1 1.2 2.1 1.3 2.2 1.4 1.5 2.3 2.4 b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: Played around a bit with it, and it ended up giving me what I needed. Thanks for the answer + explanations.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Glad if this info helped.